# Using Linq to Query XML Document

Tags: xml, linq

I don't often use Linq to query XML, and I don't have a great deal of experience with XML. What I would like to do is to query this simple XML document...

```
<AlarmParameters>
    <Parameter>
        <ParameterName>ConsecutivePoints</ParameterName>
        <Points>30</Points>
        <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
        <Caption>Consecutive Points</Caption>
    </Parameter>

    <Parameter>
        <ParameterName>SigmaCount</ParameterName>
        <Count>1</Count>
        <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
        <Caption>Number of Sigmas</Caption>
    </Parameter>
</AlarmParameters>
```

... And produce a list of 'Parameter' classes, each containing the properties shown in the XML sample. Using LinqPad, I've managed to get this far, but don't really know how to complete this.

```
string xmlFragment = "<AlarmParameters><Parameter><ParameterName>ConsecutivePoints</ParameterName><Points>30</Points><AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit><Caption>Consecutive Points</Caption></Parameter><Parameter><ParameterName>SigmaCount</ParameterName><Count>1</Count><AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit><Caption>Number of Sigmas</Caption></Parameter></AlarmParameters>";

StringReader strReader = new StringReader(xmlFragment);

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(strReader);

var result = from parameter in xmlDoc (not sure what Linq to put here next)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find some good information looking at the [LINQ to XML overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) on MSDN.  Here's one way it could be done using the `Descendants` operator to pull out a collection of elements, and the `Element` operator to pull out the subproperties of each item in the collection:

```
var result =
    from parameter in xmlDoc.Descendants("Parameter")
    select new {
        ParameterName = (string) parameter.Element("ParameterName"),
        Points = (int?) parameter.Element("Points") ?? 0,
        Count = (int?) parameter.Element("Count") ?? 0,
        AllowEdit = (bool) parameter.Element("AllowEdit"),
        Caption = (string) parameter.Element("Caption")
    };
```

This just creates anonymous class instances, but you could replace with `select new MyParameterClassName` for your parameter class.

Comment: This is almost perfect. I noticed when I execute this query, the class property values contain the value embedded in the element name (e.g., <Points>30</Points>. Any way to get rid of the element name and just get the value?

Comment: Ah. Yes, you can use `Element("..").Value`.

Comment: Also digging in a little deeper, it looks like there are built-in explicit operators so if you cast to the type you want, it will automatically cast and handle null references.  See the updated example where I added in `Count` as well.  Here's a good reference I got that from: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ImprovingLINQCodeSmellWithExplicitAndImplicitConversionOperators.aspx